# AuthorizationMessageHandler - Unable to resolve service for type IAccessTokenProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazer Technology and this a sample application I am working on.

My issue here is **AuthorizationMessageHandler is Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'**

I am following this tutorials.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=graph-sdk-4

I have .NET 6 Blazer WebAssembly Client project with below Packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="6.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.13" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
```

I have GraphAuthorizationMessageHandler.cs like below

```
public class GraphAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
    {
        public GraphAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
            NavigationManager navigation, IConfiguration config)
            : base(provider, navigation)
        {
            ConfigureHandler(
                authorizedUrls: new[] { config.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph")["BaseUrl"] },
                scopes: config.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph:Scopes").Get<List<string>>());
        }
    }
```

In Program.cs I have like below

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using MySample.WebAssembly.Client;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddTransient<GraphAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GraphAPI",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(
            builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph")["BaseUrl"]))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<GraphAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

When I run my application I get below exception in google chrome and my application is not loading properly

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' while attempting to activate 'MySample.WebAssembly.Client.GraphAuthorizationMessageHandler'.
```

What do I need to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your sample code, I haven't seen the code related to `IAccessTokenProvider` in your `code snippet`. You can follow the official way to solve the issue.

[I found a good official sample which using `GraphClientExtensions` for you](https://github.com/microsoft/assessment/tree/463b4735f7e786b164608a1363f95603b806bd7a/src/Assessment/Assessment.Web). We can find `IAccessTokenProvider` is used in `GraphAuthenticationProvider`.

Github repo: [assessment](https://github.com/microsoft/assessment/tree/463b4735f7e786b164608a1363f95603b806bd7a)

[image]

[image]