Configure HttpClient in Blazor with Individual Identity
In my .NET 8 Blazor web application, I use the "Individual Account" to authenticate the users (so I'm using Microsoft Identity). I have a server and a client project. I have some endpoints that I want to protect: the endpoints are minimum APIs in the server project under the folder Controllers. For example,
public static void MapClientEndpoints (this IEndpointRouteBuilder routes)
{
    var group = routes.MapGroup("/api/Client").WithTags(nameof(Client));

    group.MapGet("/", async (HypnoContext db) =>
    {
        return await db.Client.ToListAsync();
    })
    .RequireAuthorization()
    .WithName("GetAllClients")
    .WithOpenApi();
}

In the Program.cs, I added this code for the HttpClient:
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client => {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["FrontendUrl"]);
    })
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddTransient(sp =>
    sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ServerAPI"));

The CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler is as follows
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
           authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:7241" });
    }
}

I'm doing this because I want to make calls to the APIs exposed in the server project protected by the Individual Account. So, in a page
@inject HttpClient httpClient

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Get, "/api/Client");
await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

When I run the application, I immediately get an error:

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler
Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler': Unable to resolve
service for type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'
while attempting to activate
'MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler'.)'


So, I tried to add the following code
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtAudience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                                   builder.Configuration["JwtSecurityKey"]))
        };
    });

but this didn't help. What did I miss?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77010960/authorizationmessagehandler-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-iaccesstokenpro

@RicardoPeres thank you, I read the post but this is an old version, it is not up to date,


System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler Lifetime: Scoped
ImplementationType: MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler': Unable
to resolve service for type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'
while attempting to activate
'MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler'.)'

IAccessTokenProvider is normally implemented by RemoteAuthenticationService<TRemoteAuthenticationState,TAccount,TProviderOptions> which is added by AddOidcAuthentication or AddMsalAuthentication in the client project's Program.cs. The CustomAuthorizationHandler repro does not use server-side OIDC authentication. This means there is no IAccessTokenProvider registered anywhere.
To achieve your requirement, you'll want to use the BFF pattern to extract the token from the encrypted cookie as demonstrated in Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor Web App with OpenID Connect (OIDC) or transmit the the unencrypted access token to the client using PersistentComponentState as demonstrated in mohaaron/CustomAuthorizationHandler#1. I think that the BFF pattern is the far better option of the two though.
